# Execute Always Blocks with same value

Tags: verilog

I have a simple module that uses a few different states. The Problem I am encountering is say if I want to stay at the same state for multiple clock cycles.
In this case, my current state is synchronous and updates on clock cycle. It executes that always block which goes from state 0 -> state 1. Then once pstate reaches state 1, I attempt to have it wait to reach the next state. The reason for this is to collect data off of the data_int input. I don't care what the data is, but I need to read off it for 2 clock cycles.

I believe this doesn't work however because in the first case, I set the next state to the same value as it previously was, so it is unable to trigger. The reason I don't think I could just also add 'data_int' to the trigger list, is because its possible it remains the same value for a clock cycle and thus the always block wouldn't trigger.

I'm wondering if there is another way to do this, I guess essentially I need the always block to retrigger on clock edge as well..

```
module TestModule(
    input clk, rst, data_int);


    reg [2:0] pstate = 0;
    reg [2:0] nstate = 0;
    ref [2:0] count = 0;


    always@(pstate) begin 
        //only fires when pstate is assigned to a different value?
        //would I make a internal clock to constantly have this always run?
     if(pstate == 0) begin 
        nstate <= 1;
       end
    else if(pstate == 1) begin
      //stay at this state for multiple clock cycles
      //collect data off of data_int
      count = count + 1;
      if(count > 2) begin
         nstate <= 2;
      end else begin
        nstate <= 1;
      end
    end
   end


    always@(posedge clk, posedge rst) begin 
        if(rst) begin
            pstate <= 0;
        end
        else begin 
            pstate <= nstate; 
        end
    end
```

Comment: so something triggering on the posedge of the clk that incriments?

Answer (score 0):

1. pay attention to the usage of `=` and `<=`.
2. `count` is never reset, if you want to enter `pstate == 3'h1` state multiple times.
3. use `always@(*)` to save your life. synthesis tools will respect the logic inside the `always` block, but simulation tools won't, which will lead to simulation mismatches.

The following code is based on my understanding of your question.

```
    reg [2:0] pstate;
    reg [2:0] nstate;
    reg       count;  // 1-bit 'count' is enough to count 2 cycles

    always@(posedge clk or posedge rst)begin
        if(rst)begin
            pstate <= 3'h0;
        end
        else begin 
            pstate <= nstate;
        end
    end

    always@(*)begin
        case(pstate)
            3'h0: nstate = 3'h1;
            3'h1:begin  // lasts 2 cycles
                if(count)begin
                    nstate = 3'h2;
                end
                else begin
                    nstate = 3'h1;
                end
             3'h2: (....)
             default: (....)
            end
        endcase
    end

    always@(posedge clk or posedge rst)begin  // 'count' logic
        if(rst)begin
            count <= 1'h0;
        end
        else if((pstate == 3'h1) & count)begin  // this branch is needed if you don't
                                                // count to the max. value of 'count'
            count <= 1'b0;
        end
        else if(pstate == 3'h1)begin 
            count <= ~count;  // if 'count' is multi-bit, use 'count + 1'
        end
    end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! good to know.. so that always block is just going to continuously run then?

Comment: @joequest1 This is called 'implicit event_expression list' in LRM. Simulator will internally form the sensitivity list, and then trigger the execution of this block just like when we explicitly write down the sensitivity list.